# If $k$ is not a limit cardinal, then the cardinality of a set $E$ with $\lim\limits_{\alpha\in E}\alpha=k$ is equal to the cardinality of $k.$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals, ordinals

In chapter 1.10 of the [Tôhoku paper by Grothendieck](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178244839), near the end of the proof of theorem 1.10.1, there is a statement adapted as follows.

> Every set $E$ of ordinal numbers $\alpha\lt k$ with limit $\lim\limits_{\alpha\in E}\alpha= k$ has cardinality that of k.

Here $k$ is defined as the smallest ordinal number whose cardinality is strictly greater that the cardinality of some fixed set, say $F$ (I think if $\text{card }F=\aleph_{\lambda}$ then $k=\aleph_{\lambda+1}$).

After some futile attempts to understand how the cardinality of $E$ can affect the limit, I have found nothing particularly helpful to show this statement.

Thus any help or reference would be sincerely appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The proper term is "regular cardinal".  The axiom of choice implies that every successor cardinal is regular. Some posts have been written on this before.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the helpful hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply the statement that every successor cardinal is [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal), meaning that it is equal to its own [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality). It’s easiest to think about in terms of [von Neumann cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment), so that each cardinal is simply the set of smaller ordinals.

Let $\kappa=|E|$; then the smallest ordinal whose cardinality is greater than $\kappa$ is the ordinal (and cardinal) $\kappa^+$, the cardinal successor of $\kappa$. (This $\kappa^+$ is your $k$.) Suppose that $A\subseteq\kappa^+$, $\sup A=\kappa^+$, and $|A|<\kappa^+$. Then

$$\kappa^+=\bigcup A=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\alpha\;,$$

and $|\alpha|\le\alpha<\kappa^+$ for each $\alpha\in A$, so $|\alpha|\le\kappa$ for each $\alpha\in A$, and

$$\kappa^+=\left|\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\alpha\right|\le\kappa\cdot|A|\;.$$

If $|A|<\kappa^+$, then $|A|\le\kappa$, and $\kappa\cdot|A|=\kappa<\kappa^+$, which is impossible, so we must have $|A|=\kappa^+$. (Clearly $|A|\le\kappa^+$, since $A\subseteq\kappa^+$.)

Comment: Thanks, I have to bend my head around the notion of regular ordinals...

Comment: @awllower: The short version: a regular cardinal is one that is not the sum of a smaller number of smaller cardinals. $\omega$ (or $\aleph_0$, if you prefer) is regular: it is not the sum of a finite number of finite cardinals. So is $\omega_1$ (or $\aleph_1$): it is not the some of a countable number of countable cardinals. Equivalently, a regular cardinal is not the union of a smaller number of smaller ordinals.

Comment: Thanks, I have finally wrapped my head around this notion. Quite ingenious! :D

Comment: @awllower: You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott really a nitpick: not sure about $|\alpha|\le\alpha\le\kappa$. I think from $\alpha<\kappa^+$, all we can conclude is that $|\alpha|<\kappa^+$ and hence $|\alpha|\le\kappa$.

Comment: @PatrickR: You’re right, of course; thanks! I can’t guess now whether I meant to write simply $|alpha|\le\kappa$, or whether I somehow got ahead of myself and collapsed what I’ve now written down to the incorrect inequality.

Answer (score 3):

There is a concept of "regular cardinal" which means that there is no increasing function $f:\alpha\to\kappa$ with $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $\sup \{f(\beta):\beta<\alpha\}=\kappa$. It is known that every successor cardinal is regular. This is very standard and I think it would be easy to find a reference with this names.

You can find it in the book Hrbacek-Jech: Introduction to set theory, or in http://www.math.unt.edu/~moliver/fa04s/JacksonNotes/card.pdf , Lemma 2.6 (using also Theorem 1.8))

In your case, since $\kappa$ is a successor cardinal (namely, $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$), then it is regular, and if $E=\{\beta_i:i<\alpha\}$ is a subset of ordinals $\beta_i<\kappa$, also with $\alpha<\kappa$ then by defining 
\begin{align*}
f: &\alpha\longrightarrow \kappa\\
&i\longmapsto \beta_i
\end{align*}
you will contradict the fact that $\kappa$ is regular.

Comment: Thanks, the linked paper helps a lot!

Comment: I am glad that you found it useful. It was literally the first document with proofs I found after googling "every successor cardinal is regular"